# Почему не работает регулярное выражение в postgresql?

Tags: массивы, регулярные-выражения, postgresql

Есть строка 'L-37,38,39,40' и любое количество циферок через запятую. Хочу получить в массиве первую букву и все цифры, но получаю лишь букву, первую цифру и последнюю. Как сделать правильно

```
select regexp_matches('L-37,38,39,40', '^(\w)-(\d+)(?:,(\d+))*$');
```

Result:
{L,37,40}

А хотелось бы {L, 37, 38, 39, 40}

Или есть возможность получить массив значений {L-37, L-38, L-39, L-40}

Comment: Нет, так не получится.

Comment: Почему вы не хотите использовать `select regexp_matches('L-37,38,39,40', '\w+', 'g');`?

Comment: Потому что есть много вариантов таких как 'L-37-38,39,40', 'L-37-38-39-40-а,б,в' и тому подобных к примеру

Comment: Тогда используйте что-то вроде `if col ~ '^\w-\d+(?:,\d+)*$' then regexp_matches(col, '\w+', 'g');`. В регулярных выражениях PostgreSQL нет поддержки оператора `\G`

Comment: Что-нибудь  у вас сработало?